# Error due to invalid combination of Toast and OnClickListener

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to use `Toast` inside `OnCLickListener`. My code triggers the following error:

```
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)
```

This is my code:

```
    Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
            String Lname = name.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(this, Lname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

As The Kenny said, `this` is refering to the `View.OnClickListener` instead of your `Activity`. Change this, to `MyActivity.this`.

For example,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
// ... other code here
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, Lname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: MyActivity.this. Thanks. Couldn't remember how to refer to the this of the enclosing class.

Comment: The Kenny - I can't tell you how many times I've seen questions just like this on SO. Every single time I have to look it up in my source code. You'd think I would learn.

Comment: apart from myActivity.this you can also use getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 7):

In this case, `this` refers to the instance of the anonymous subclass of `View.OnClickListener`. You have to refer to the `this` of the class where you create the anonymous class.

Answer (score 4):

Use `MyActivity.this` as `this` refers to your `onclickListener`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getApplicationContext()` as well. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Anywhere, just use the following:

```
((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast my_toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "YOUR TEXT OR STRING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        my_toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        my_toast.show();
                    }
                });
```

You just need to define at the top of your activity (just after the onCreate):

```
mContext = this;
```

Also, see that I decomposed it a bit to be able to handle the gravity as I want (sometimes you may want the toast to appear at the center of the screen)...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to achieve your goal is to implement the `OnClickListener` interface. This way you implement the `onClick()` method in your `Activity` and you could thus assign `this`. In addition, you can assign `this` to multiple `Button`s. You can distinguish these `Button`s from each other by comparing their IDs via an appropriate `if`, respectively `switch` statement within the `onClick()` method.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    // ...

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // ...
        Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        String text = name.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        String Lname = name.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), Lname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```